# FFmpeg, Icecast and metadata

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, icecast

I use FFmpeg streaming to the Icecast server on my Windows machine in the following way (sound card line in):

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -channels 2 -i audio="Line In" -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -legacy_icecast 1 -content_type audio/mpeg -ice_name "Radio test 1" -ice_description "This is Radio test 1" -ice_genre "Rock" -ice_url "http://www.radiotest.com" -f mp3 icecast://source:password@ip:port/mountpoint
```

This works ok.

But I noticed an Icecast statistics that FFmpeg do not send "audio_info" metadata to Icecast while than edcast/altacast etc send it. And edcast/altacast do not send "user_agent" while FFmpeg is forced to send it.

Do I get FFmpeg to send "audio_info" metadata to Icecast?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to have it send the per-track metadata from FFmpeg.  You'll have to send metadata updates out-of-band using another script.

Answer (score 0):

For MP3 this can't work as MP3 streaming does not support proper metadata. You will need an extra script that calls Icecasts metadata update endpoint.

For Ogg this can work but afaik not with FFmpeg as there is no way to trigger it to add metadata and start a new chained Ogg "segment".

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment but here is a start..

```
/**
 * Please be aware. This gist requires at least PHP 5.4 to run correctly.
 * Otherwise consider downgrading the $opts array code to the classic "array" syntax.
 */
function getmp3StreamTitle($streamingUrl, $interval = 19200)
{
    $needle = 'StreamTitle=';
    $ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36';
    $opts = array('http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => 'Icy-MetaData: 1',
        'user_agent' => $ua
    ));

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $stream = fopen($streamingUrl, 'r', false, $context);
    if(!$stream) throw new Exception("Unable to open stream [{$streamingUrl}]");

    while(true) {
        $buffer = stream_get_contents($stream, $interval);
        if($buffer === false) throw new Exception('Could not read from stream.');

        if(strpos($buffer, $needle) !== false)
        {
            $text = explode($needle, $buffer)[1];
            $songtext = substr($text, 1, strpos($text, ';') - 2);
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose($stream);

    return $songtext;
}

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header('Content-type: application/json');
```